# How do i parse a text file that has json and get array element

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jsonparser, jsonslurper

I am trying to parse a text file with json and get one of the element from jsonArray. Below is the json i am trying to parse

```
[
  {
    "ContainerConfig": {
      "Labels": {
        "commit-id": "abcdef123d",
        "author": "Jon"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Below is my groovy implementation in jenkinsfile

```
def jsonStr=readFile('temp.txt').trim()
//here temp.txt consist of above json 

JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def parsedJson=slurper.parseText(jsonStr)

def commitId=parsedJson[0].ContainerConfig.Labels.commit-id
```

I am getting this errorMsg -

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.EchoStep.message expects class java.lang.String but received class java.util.ArrayList
```

Comment: you did it. the error message is saying that you try to do `echo(array)`. you must to cast array to string to `echo` it. like this: `echo(array as String)`

Comment: i removed echo from my code now i am getting this error - hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: id for class:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the JsonSlurper is not really best practice and can cause problems with CPS, use [readJSON](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace) instead (which is also easier to use IMO).

I also suspect that the `-` in `commit-id` causes the error and you should the `["commit-id"]` snytax instead.

Comment: Great thnx for suggestion i changed it to readJson and it worked like a charm